# How can I look up a reference to a remote actor from a different system in akka?

Tags: java, akka, remoting

I have an ActorSystem running on port 2552 and another running on port 2553. Each of them create an Actor which instantiates a singleton object. I now want to create another system that manages both of these systems and can reference these actors in order to make use of the singletons simultaneously.

I know the actors are listening on the port because it gives me a log like this for each port

```
 Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://singletonApplication@127.0.0.1:2552]
```

and it when I look at the object using the debugger the actor shows up like this

```
 Actor[akka://singletonApplication/user/singleton]
```

I create the manager system using

```
 ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("managerSystem");
```

but when I try and reference the remote actors by the following line

```
 system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://singletonApplication@127.0.0.1:2552/user/singleton");
```

It gives me this in the object

```
 ActorSelection[Actor[akka://managerApplication/deadLetters]/user/singleton]
```

and when I try and send it a message it gives me a deadletter error log in the console
I am not really sure what I doing wrong but it looks like the system I am trying to use to look up the remote actors is messing up my actorSelection call. Do I need to be within the same system in order to reference a remote actor? I thought this was one of the points to using akka?

Comment: You should check your config for akka and make sure you are using the RemoteActorRefProvider instead of the default LocalActorRefProvider in the system in which you are attempting to lookup the remote actors.

Comment: Yes, cmbaxter is very probably right, if you get this output with RemoteActorRefProvider (or ClusterActorRefProvider) then please file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you are accessing the remote actor from a different system. But i see that you are using 127.0.0.1 to address the remote system. 127.0.0.1 is a special loopback address and refers to the local machine. So you need to give addressable IP to access remote machine.

For more on Loopback check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

This is also clearly stated in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/remoting.html):

"Note

Be sure to replace the default IP 127.0.0.1 with the real address the system is reachable by if you deploy onto multiple machines!
"

Comment: Yes but I am testing it locally so right now I am running the actors on the same machine through different applications and on different ports.

Comment: But i see your port is also same ( 2552 ) as per your post